# Ударение в словах ед. и мн. числа

Tags: фонетика

Корт, форт, порт, торт, сорт, болт, винт.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужна НОРМА, то: корт - кОрты, форт - фортЫ, порт - пОрты, торт - тОрты, сорт-сортА, болт - болтЫ, винт - винтЫ. Все слова есть в Викисловаре, легко проверить.

Comment: Людмила! 
Викисловарь - не лучший источник. Есть же вести куда более авторитетные издания.  
А вот то, что топикстартер спрашивает об ударении в формах *единственного* числа почему-то никого (кроме меня) не позабавило... А ведь их даже в словарях нет.

Comment: Для учеников Вики в самый раз, пусть хотя бы туда почаще заглядывают вместо того, чтобы отнимать у людей время.А чем Вас это позабавило? В формах ед.ч. в косвенных падежах бывают сложности, сами же приводили пример. В Викисловаре есть ВСЕ формы. К тому же я уважаю любой вопрос. Если спрашивает - значит, ему это нужно знать. Над вопросом смеяться не привыкла. Он не за этим сюда обратился. Я так часто отвечала на действительно глупые вопросы, что этот кажется вполне приличным.

Answer (score 0):

Сложный вопрос. Особенно в "словах ед. числа". 
Даже в словарях нет.

---

> Так пОрты или портЫ(портА)? бОлт - бОлты или болтЫ, тОрты или тортЫ?

Подобные вопросы обычно решаются в словарном порядке, единого правила нет, если вы об этом. 
тОрты и болтЫ.

С "портами" сложнее. Строго литературно - пОрты; портЫ - это штаны.
Но в профессиональном языке под действием морского обычая происходит смещение на флексию, причем в разных значениях, включая компьютерный сленг. Так что портЫ - это как бы профессиональный жаргон, не только морской. Хотя это в именительном и косвенных падежах это проявляется в разной степени, обычно всё-таки используется нечто среднее: пОрты, но портОв, портАм... о пОрте, но в портУ.     
В такой ситуации установить единую и однозначную норму не представляется возможным.

С остальными словами тоже надо разбираться отдельно, но подбных сложностей там не возникает, все вполне однозначно: кОрты, фортЫ, сортА и т.д. ВинтЫ  - тут я даже не могу представить, какие еще варианты могут быть.

Достаточно хорошие и удобные словари есть, например, тут: 
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E1%EE%EB%F2

Comment: Так пОрты или портЫ(портА)? бОлт - бОлты или болтЫ, тОрты или тортЫ?

Comment: Так "ед. число" или ударение?

Comment: Хоть и заглядывал я встарь в википедический словарь : " Им.
винт
винты́
Р.
винта́
винто́в
Д.
винту́
винта́м
В.
винт
винты́
Тв.
винто́м
винта́ми
Пр.
винте́
винта́х"